# MongoDb pass string to number and use a conditional

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have these fields:

```
{
    _id: {}
    contents: [{
        duration: "4",
        startDate : "2020-10-14",
    }, {
        duration: "15",
        startDate : "2020-11-17",
    }], 

}
```

And I need to find the contents that will expire in the next 10 days. This is the logic I came up to:

```
db.collection.find() 
    If duration > 10 =>  
        If ((duration - 10) + startDate) ==== today
```

Is there a way to resolve this via only querys?

Comment: your data has `contents` inside `_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can run `aggregate` with match stage

The logic the below code is running is (pseudo code)

If the below is true then return the document

`(startDate + duration >= now) && (startDate + duration <= now+10 days)`

Mongo code:

```
db.content.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$and": [ 
          { 
            "$gte": [ 
              {"$add": [ {
                "$dateFromString": {
                  "dateString": "$startDate"
                }
              }, {"$multiply": [ {"$toInt": "$duration"}, 24*60*60000 ]} ]},
              "$$NOW" ]
          }, 
            
          { 
            "$lte": [ 
              {"$add": [ {
                "$dateFromString": {
                  "dateString": "$startDate"
                }
              }, {"$multiply": [ {"$toInt": "$duration"}, 24*60*60000 ]} ]},
              {"$add": [ "$$NOW", 10*24*60*60000 ]} 
            ]
          } 
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the long answer!
But I can't access to '$duration' or '$startDate'. Could it be that I need to use $unwind to destructure the array and then access to duration and startDate?

For example if I do ```"contents.duration": { $gt: "10" }``` it works, but if I do ```"duration": { $gt: "10" }``` it won't work

And if I do 
```db.groupdistributions.aggregate([ {  $unwind : "$contents"  }, {  "$addFields": { "expired_at": { "$toDate": "$contents.startDate" } } } ``` It works

Comment: Yup you can try that. I designed the query based on the example you have given